# Leveberg-Marquard Optimization for Intensity-based Image Alignment Matlab Failed

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab

I am trying to implement the intensity-based image alignment algorithm in the paper [Efficient, Robust, and Fast Global Motion Estimation for Video Coding](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/826785/) on MATLAB. The problem is that the Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) optimization doesn't work properly, so the energy function cannot approach even a local minima due to very tiny update term computed from the LM approximation equation. I've searching for a week but still could not figure out the problem. Here is my implementation.

I have two gray images **I** and **T** equal in size (W x H) and would like to estimate a rigid transformation **F** (scale + rotation + translation) that aligns **I** onto **T**. This could be obtained by minimizing the following energy function

[image]

Where

[image]

According to LM, I can derive the gradient term of E with respect to each parameter **a_i** (i=1,4) as follow (from equation (5) in the paper).

[image]

And the terms of the Hessian matrix of **E** are (from equation (4) in the paper)

[image]

From the above equations, I derive the bellow MATLAB procedure to compute beta and alpha terms.

```
%========== 1. Compute gradient of T using Sobel filter
gx = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1] / 4;
gy = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1] / 4;

Tx = conv2( T, gx, 'same' );
Ty = conv2( T, gy, 'same' );

%========== 2. Warp I using F to compute diff_image = I(x, y) - T(F(x,y,a)). F was previously initialized by an identity matrix of size 3x3
tform = affine2d( F );
I_warp = imwarp( I, tform, 'linear', 'OutputView', imref2d( size( T ) ) );
diff_img = I_wapr - T;

% create a mask for overlaping region between two aligned images
mask = ones( size( T ) );
mask_warp = imwarp( mask, tform, 'nearest', 'OutputView', imref2d( size( T ) ) );
overlap_area = numel( mask_warp ); 
diff_img = diff_img .* mask;
error = sum( sum( diff_img ) ) / 2 / overlap_area;

% create x, y grids 
[y, x] = ndgrid( 0 : h-1, 0 : w-1 );
x_warp = imwarp( x, t_form, 'nearest', 'OutputView', imref2d( size(T) ) );
y_warp = imwarp( y, t_form, 'nearest', 'OutputView', imref2d( size(T) ) );

%======== compute beta_i = - dE/da_i (i=1,4)
sx = Tx .* diff_img;
sy = Ty .* diff_img;

beta_1 = sum( sum( x_warp .* sx + y_warp .* sy ) );
beta_2 = sum( sum( y_warp .* sx - x_warp .* sy ) );
beta_3 = sum( sum( sx ) );
beta_4 = sum( sum( sy ) );
beta = -[beta_1; beta_2; beta_3; beta_4] / overlap_area;

%======= compute alpha_ij = (dE/da_i) * (dE/da_j)  i,j = 1,4
Sxx = (Tx .^ 2) .* mask_warp;
Syy = (Ty .^ 2) .* mask_warp;
Sxy = (Tx.* Ty) .* mask_warp;

xx = x_warp .^2;
yy = y_warp .^2;
xy = x_warp .* y_warp;

alpha_11 = sum( sum( xx .* Sxx + 2 * xy .* Sxy + yy .* Syy ) );
alpha_12 = sum( sum( (yy - xx) .* Sxy + xy .* (Sxx - Syy) ) );
alpha_13 = sum( sum( x .* Sxx + y .* Sxy ) );
alpha_14 = sum( sum( x .* Sxy + y .* Syy ) );
alpha_22 = sum( sum( yy .* Sxx - 2 * xy .* Sxy + xx .* Syy ) );
alpha_23 = sum( sum( y .* Sxx - x .* Sxy ) );
alpha_24 = sum( sum( y .* Sxy - x .* Syy ) );
alpha_33 = sum( sum( Sxx ) );
alpha_34 = sum( sum( Sxy ) );
alpha_44 = sum( sum( Syy ) );

alpha = [alpha_11 alpha_12 alpha_13 alpha_14;
         alpha_12 alpha_22 alpha_23 alpha_24;
         alpha_13 alpha_23 alpha_33 alpha_34;
         alpha_14 alpha_24 alpha_34 alpha_44] / overlap_area;
% With lamda was previously initialized by 0.0001
for i = 1 : 4
    alpha(i, i) = alpha(i, i) * (lamda + 1);
end

%======== Find the update term: delta_a = alpha^(-1) * beta
delta_a = pinv( alpha ) * beta

% Or we can solve for delta_a using SVD
%[U, S, V] = svd( alpha );
%inv_S = S;
%for ii = 1 : size(S, 1)
%    if S(ii, ii)
%        inv_S(ii, ii) = 1 / S(ii, ii);
%    end
%end
%delta_a = V * inv_S * U' * beta;

%======== Update a_i and new error value
a = [   F(1, 1)-1;
        F(2, 1);
        F(3, 1);
        F(3, 2)];
new_a = a + delta_a;
new_F = [new_a(1)+1   -new_a(2)    0;
          new_a(2)    new_a(1)+1   0;
          new_a(3)     new_a(4)    1];

tform = affine2d( new_F );
mask_warp = imwarp( mask, tform, 'nearest', 'OutputView', imref2d(size(T)));
new_I_warp = imwarp( I, tform, 'linear', 'OutputView', imref2d(size(T)));
new_diff_img = (new_I_warp - T) .* mask_warp;
new_error = sum( sum( new_diff_img .^2 ) ) / 2/ sum( sum( mask_warp ) );

if( new_error > error )
    lamda = lamda * 10;
elseif new_error < error
    lamda = lamda /10;
```

The above process is repeated until the iteration reach the limitation or the new_error value less than a predetermined threshold. However, after each iteration, the update terms are too small that parameters make trivial movement. For example,

```
delta a = 1.0e-04 * [0.0011   -0.0002    0.2186    0.2079]
```

Is there anybody know how to fixed it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think the C++ tag is all that relevant to this question. Recommend removing it or better justifying it.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I've amended it